# How to wire outdoor post lamp if power comes via two black wires?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, outdoor

Strong winds damaged one of my post lamps so I am replacing it. It comes with three wires: black, white, and bare.
The top of my column however only has two black wires coming out of it. How should I wire it up?

FWIW all the lighting in my yard is controlled by a single physical dial-type timer that is plugged into an outlet.

Comment: Assuming its a metal post, the bare wire would be connected to the post.

Answer (score 4):

The bare wire is safety ground.

Most lamps, especially  LED lamps, don't care a lot about which side is connected to hot and which to neutral, which is why they're both black -- it saved the manufacturer a fraction of a cent per lamp. Hook either one to black and the other to white.